# It says Whatsapp version expired and update required

Tags: whatsapp

I have Nokia Lumia 630 with Windows Phone update 8.1
WhatsApp Version 2.16.172.0 Last auto updated on 22/08.
I am getting error message "This version of WhatsApp has expired. Please go to the Windows Phone Store and update it". But in WhatsApp install screen it say App installed and options are available only for View and Share and not for Update anywhere.
My date settings are proper and it is auto update. My messages are seem to be downloaded and unread messages keep on increasing (I even tried setting the date back by 25 days; still the status is the same). But I am not able to enter the screen. So I want to see my Chat history (Some important msgs read/unread are there); use my WhatsApp; Is there any way to update or re-install without using the Chat history?
This started happening after changing with another sim card 2-3 times. But no activity done with either sim cards. Now back to the original sim card and find error.

Comment: Hi dear I have Lumia 535 with same issue and I tried all possible options but still issue remains please update me if any one got solution.

Comment: Same here. I can't open WhatsApp from 1/09/2016. Anybody pls help.

Comment: backup your messages, uninstall whatsapp, restart your phone and install it again! it will solve your problem!

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem.

I unistalled WhatsApp, then i installed it from the store.

After that, the app gave me the option to restore all the conversations stored in the phone.